# Future causing an infinite loop

Tags: java

I have Java code that looks like this...

```
package java.uyil.concurrent;
...


Future<> future= ...;
try {
    while(!future.isDone()) {
    }
}catch(Exception e) {
}
```

Basically the code is supposed to run that while loop until the future task is done. For some reason this code fails om one user's PC and the loop seems to go on forever. On other PCs it runs okay.

Am I missing something and does someone know threading and Future tasks enough to help?

Comment: You are missing the code that shows the problem. Please show us what the `Future` looks like.

Answer (score 3):

So you want to block the flow until you get the result from the future. You do not need to use while loop, rather directly use `future.get()` which will block until you get the result.

Comment: OP does not need to use while loop to achieve the functionality he needs. He is probably not aware of get.

Comment: Like I said, this is a good point and good advice, but it doesn't help answering the question.

Comment: @Keppil Since we don't really know what the problem is, it's difficult to tell whether it will solve the problem or not. There is a very good chance though that it will, as spin-waiting on a single-CPU machine might mean that the background thread is never actually executed.

Comment: @akhil_mittal `You do not need to use while loop`, in fact I'd go as far as to say you must not use a while loop.

Comment: @biziclop: I would say that there is a close to zero percent chance that OPs problem is caused by a background thread being locked due to spin-waiting, as no modern processor or system would behave like that. There might be another reason that this will solve the issue (see Peter Lawreys answer), but that is not mentioned here, and without the `Future` code it is impossible to say.

Comment: @Keppil Fair enough. The only way to be sure would be for OP to clarify.

Answer (score 1):

If you cancel a Future before it starts, it will never get to `isDone() == true`

From the Javadoc for Future.isDone()

> @return {@code true} if this task completed

If you don't want to use `Future.get()` you could do

```
while(!future.isDone() && !future.isCancelled()) {
    Thread.yield();
}
```